# io.confluent.ksql.exception.KafkaTopicExistsException: when launching ksql-server-start ksql-server.properties

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb, kafka-topic

I'm working with ksql from quite some time. Kafka cluster if of 3 nodes. I've been using udf as well and all looks good until I stop the servers and start them again.
On server start I'm seeing the following in the logs:

```
[2019-04-03 11:29:54,381] ERROR Exception encountered running command: A Kafka topic with the name 'czxcorp-structured-data-enriched' already exists, with different partition/replica configuration than required. KSQL expects 4 partitions (topic has 9), and 1 replication factor (topic has 1).. Retrying in 5000 ms (io.confluent.ksql.util.RetryUtil:80)
[2019-04-03 11:29:54,381] ERROR Stack trace: io.confluent.ksql.exception.KafkaTopicExistsException: A Kafka topic with the name 'czxcorp-structured-data-enriched' already exists, with different partition/replica configuration than required. KSQL expects 4 partitions (topic has 9), and 1 replication factor (topic has 1).
        at io.confluent.ksql.services.TopicValidationUtil.validateTopicProperties(TopicValidationUtil.java:51)
        at io.confluent.ksql.services.TopicValidationUtil.validateTopicProperties(TopicValidationUtil.java:35)
        at io.confluent.ksql.services.KafkaTopicClientImpl.validateTopicProperties(KafkaTopicClientImpl.java:292)
        at io.confluent.ksql.services.KafkaTopicClientImpl.createTopic(KafkaTopicClientImpl.java:76)
        at io.confluent.ksql.planner.plan.KsqlStructuredDataOutputNode.createSinkTopic(KsqlStructuredDataOutputNode.java:244)
        at io.confluent.ksql.planner.plan.KsqlStructuredDataOutputNode.buildStream(KsqlStructuredDataOutputNode.java:146)
        at io.confluent.ksql.physical.PhysicalPlanBuilder.buildPhysicalPlan(PhysicalPlanBuilder.java:106)
        at io.confluent.ksql.QueryEngine.buildPhysicalPlan(QueryEngine.java:113)
        at io.confluent.ksql.KsqlEngine$EngineExecutor.execute(KsqlEngine.java:625)
        at io.confluent.ksql.KsqlEngine$EngineExecutor.access$800(KsqlEngine.java:577)
        at io.confluent.ksql.KsqlEngine.execute(KsqlEngine.java:247)
        at io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.computation.StatementExecutor.startQuery(StatementExecutor.java:277)
        at io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.computation.StatementExecutor.executeStatement(StatementExecutor.java:191)
        at io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.computation.StatementExecutor.handleStatementWithTerminatedQueries(StatementExecutor.java:167)
        at io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.computation.StatementExecutor.handleRestore(StatementExecutor.java:101)
        at io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.computation.CommandRunner.lambda$null$0(CommandRunner.java:139)
        at io.confluent.ksql.util.RetryUtil.retryWithBackoff(RetryUtil.java:63)
        at io.confluent.ksql.util.RetryUtil.retryWithBackoff(RetryUtil.java:36)
        at io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.computation.CommandRunner.lambda$processPriorCommands$1(CommandRunner.java:135)
        at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
        at io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.computation.CommandRunner.processPriorCommands(CommandRunner.java:134)
        at io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlRestApplication.buildApplication(KsqlRestApplication.java:414)
        at io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlServerMain.createExecutable(KsqlServerMain.java:80)
        at io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlServerMain.main(KsqlServerMain.java:42)
 (io.confluent.ksql.util.RetryUtil:84)
```

Though I've stopped/terminated all the queries, the log prints all the commands I've executed from the beginning for my testing till data, including `create, select, drop`. I've pulled out the `.jar`(UDF) from /ext folder and the server started, though the log prints udf function(i'm using) not available.

This is my ksql-server.properties:

```
bootstrap.servers=hostname:9092
service.id=cyan_ksql
commit.interval.ms=5000
cache.max.bytes.buffering=20000000
num.stream.threads=10
fail.on.deserialization.error=false
listeners=http://localhost:8088
ksql.extension.dir=/opt/ksql-master/ext/
```

Going nuts with the error. I'm deleting the topic and somehow its recreated. Someone please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the error:

```
A Kafka topic with the name 'czxcorp-structured-data-enriched' already exists, with different partition/replica configuration than required. 
KSQL expects 4 partitions (topic has 9), and 1 replication factor (topic has 1)
```

If you've deleted the topic then either

- it didn't actually get deleted
- it got deleted and something else recreated it with nine partitions and your erroring KSQL query has not specified an override (`WITH (PARTITIONS=9`) to the default four
- another KSQL command is creating it ahead of the one that errors out and your erroring KSQL query has not specified an override (`WITH (PARTITIONS=9`) to the default four

If you want to blow away your state and start from scratch, simply change your `ksql.service.id` which will cause KSQL to use a new command topic (which is what get replayed when you restart the process)

Comment: Beautiful. It works with change in ksql.service.id. Thanks Robin.
I've updated the question, would you please suggest the corrections  in the ksql-server.properties? Thanks

Comment: You can change `service.id` in the properties file - is that what you mean? Not sure what you're asking

Comment: Well, I've a change of service.id and the ksql server started all over new. No problem at all. My ask is about any changes/additional parameters required other than the once mentioned in original question for better performance?

Comment: I'd recommend starting a new question, and detail the performance problems that you're encountering that you're looking to resolve. thanks.